# Cypher file as parameter in py2neo python

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to pass a `cypher` file as parameter in py2neo to have the variables in the queries as other parameters. 
Instead of:

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph(password = "*****")

def test(some_things):
    result = graph.run(
                "MATCH (movie:movies)"
                "where movie.name =~ $name "
                "RETURN movie",{"name":"(?i).*" + some_things+ ".*"})
    return result
```

I am wondering if there is something like this:

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph(password = "*****")

def test(some_things):
    result = graph.run("some_cypher.cypher", some_things)
    return result
```

where `some_cypher.cypher` could be:

```
MATCH (movie:movies) where movie.name =~ $name RETURN movie, ,{"name":"(?i).*" + ?+ ".*"}
```

with `?` being the parameter to be replaced in the python file by `some_things`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no built-in option to read directly from a file in py2neo, there is a mechanism to get a sequence of parameters as you want. So, what remains is just using a function to read the query from the file and use the parameters. This should look something along the lines of:

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph(password = "*****")


def run_query_from_file(cypher_file_path,  parameters=None, **kwparameters):
    with open(cypher_file_path, 'r') as cypher_file:
          cypher_query = cypher_file.read().strip()
    graph.run(cypher_query, parameters)

def test1(dict_of_parameters):
    result = run_query_from_file("some_cypher.cypher", dict_of_parameters)
    return result

def test2(**kwparameters):
    result = run_query_from_file("some_cypher.cypher", **kwparameters)
    return result

# Both should work
test1({'username': 'abc', 'password': '123'})
test2('username'='abc', 'password'='123')
```

where `some_cypher.cypher` contains:

> MERGE (user:User {username:$username})
>              WITH user, user.password as user_password
>              SET user.password = $password
>              RETURN user_password

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality built into py2neo. You'll have to roll your own function if you want to do that.